# Display the data on GridView by built SQL from multi tables

Tags: c#, asp.net

GridView1 does not display the data that the SQL statement brings
as :

.....{statements to select attributes and conditions to putting SQL statement}
(Example on SQL :SELECT [patient].name_patient FROM patient, visitFACTABLE, datetime, disease WHERE [patient].Id_patient = [visitFACTABLE].Id AND [visitFACTABLE].Id = [datetime].Id_datetime AND [patient].gender_patient = 'Male')

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    con.Open();
    string q_sql = "SELECT " + slct + " FROM patient, visitFACTABLE, datetime, disease WHERE [patient].Id_patient = [visitFACTABLE].Id AND [visitFACTABLE].Id = [datetime].Id_datetime " + w;SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(q_sql, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trigger debugger break point  @  GridView1.DataSource = dt;

[image]

then hover visualize  and check did your dt ( data table) contain at least 1 row . if got row , by right your Gridview shall show data